# Cannot load Krypton Toolkit controls in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, krypton-toolkit, krypton

After converting with Visual Studio 2013 a C# project created with Visual Studio 2010 and using Component Factory Krypton Toolkit v4.4.0 controls, I can't add the Krypton Toolkit controls to the tool box.

In Visual Studio 2013, when I try to add the controls to the tool box from the library `C:\Program Files (x86)\Component Factory\Krypton Toolkit 4.4.0\Bin\ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.dll` I'm getting an error because it doesn't find the file `ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.tlb`.

Is there a way to import the Windows Forms controls from the library without having this .tlb file?

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling Krypton (because is probably not integrated with VS2013) and importing Krypton toolkit in the VS2013 Toolbox again.

I managed to migrate a project from VS2010 with Krypton to VS2013 with no big issues.